# Are there ways to run testing scripts on an Android device directly?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am currently testing an app for Android phones using the Espresso library with local devices as well as the Google Firebase Test Lab. For a good portion of these tests to be functional the phone running the test needs to connect to another phone or at least receive feedback from another device. I have been trying to do some research but really can't find anything on what I'm looking to do, seeing that it isn't a common practice.

Is there away to run Espresso or any small script directly on an Android device? I just need a script to sit idle or looping until it receives the information from the tested device, accepts it so the test can continue. I am not trying to alter any direct code in my app to auto accept things, I want to keep the app itself as untouched as possible. And I could manually do it on a small scale, but with Firebase I would like to test lots of devices at once or will run tests daily, sometimes when I'm not there for feedback. I want to automate this process as much as possible, so anything that could do that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I've automated this process completely. The best thing is that you don't have to keep busy of your Android Studio and resources. Everything is done remotely.

You can use this plugin to setup Firebase test lab:

https://github.com/piotrmadry/firebase-test-lab-gradle-plugin

Hopefully you have CI (Continuous Integration) for your project.

So after your setup for test lab (you can define as many devices as you want)

You can create 2 parallel jobs on you CI:

- First - it would build your project in normal way
- Second - would run android task created by plugin `./gradlew uploadTestLab`. After this job you will be able to look at results in Firebase Console.